# file not found error, though file is in proper place

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, windows-10

```
C:\Users\ebena\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/ebena/PycharmProjects/untitled2/trial.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ebena/PycharmProjects/untitled2/trial.py", line 5, in <module>
    image = Image.open("book background.jpeg")
  File "C:\Users\ebena\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2878, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'book background.jpeg'
```

python cannot access these files and says they do not exist or file not found

Comment: Try to put this command on the line just before the one that throws the error `import os; print(os.getcwd())`. Is the printed directory the same as the one the picture is located in?

Comment: Do you actually have a file at ``C:\Users\ebena\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\Scripts\book background.jpeg``? Are you sure you don't want a file at ``C:/Users/ebena/PycharmProjects/untitled2/book background.jpeg``?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change the name of the file to book_background.jpeg